# Format time from decimal in Make (Integromat)

Tags: time, format, make.com

I have a scenario in Make which gets data from a webhook. This data contains 2 timestamps. I subtract these numbers and that leaves the duration of a few minutes. Only the format is in in decimals: 0.03422453704
I need this in hh.mm.ss (so in this case 00:02:03)
How can I set this format?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a formula like this one:
[image]

I tested this scenario with just two modules ("Basic trigger" for the input value and "Set variable" for the calculation). For the input you provided the output is "00:02:03".

This is an exported Blueprint: https://sharetext.me/4dhvrxexqc

[image]